# It says ParserError: Expected ';' but got 'StringLiteral' --> Token.sol:495:16: | 495 | address"msgSender" = _msgSender(); when I compile it

Tags: blockchain, solidity

/**
* @dev Initializes the contract setting the deployer as the initial owner.
*/
constructor () internal {
address"msgSender" = _msgSender();
_owner = msgSender;
emit OwnershipTransferred(address(0), msgSender);
}

```
/**
 * @dev Returns the address of the current owner.
 */
function owner() public view returns (address) {
    return _owner;
}

/**
 * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
 */
modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(_owner == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
    _;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more complete code to get help like where _msgSender() is defined. Can you post the full Token.sol contract?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this function:

```
 /** 
  * @dev Initializes the contract setting the deployer as the initial owner.
  */ 
  constructor () internal { 
    address"msgSender" = _msgSender();
    _owner = msgSender;
    emit OwnershipTransferred(address(0), msgSender); 
  }
```

Make it as follow and the problem should be solved:

```
 /** 
  * @dev Initializes the contract setting the deployer as the initial owner.
  */ 
  constructor () internal { 
    _owner = msg.sender;
    emit OwnershipTransferred(address(0), msg.sender); 
  }
```